# The Haste package 'react-native-vector-icons' error in react-native 0.52.1

Tags: react-native

facing following error in `react-native 0.52.1`

> While resolving module `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome`, the
>   Haste package `react-native-vector-icons` was found. However the
>   module`FontAwesome` could not be found within the package.

earlier I was in 0.50.3 and no issue then. Some people suggested in github(https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/630)  to delete the following file

> ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/fixtures/files/package.json

is it good practice or permanent solution to this issue? Will be there be any further conflicts if proceed to do so?

Comment: Used it, didn't get any other issues. It's almost a month now of daily development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's a react-native issue** https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17610 !

Will be fixed by https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17672

**Workaround**

addition of rn-cli.config.js (for RN 0.52 at least):

```
  const blacklist = require('metro/src/blacklist')
  module.exports = {
    getBlacklistRE () {
      return blacklist([/react-native\/local-cli\/core\/__fixtures__.*/])
    },
  }
```

`rn-cli.config.js` should be located in the root directory of the project. It is location where RN will find it automatically (facebook/react-native#7271).

Source: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/626#issuecomment-362386341

Comment: Can't tell until the PR is merged. Best thing you can do is to make a bit of noize on the PR :)

Comment: You mean, Do i have to take any action to push it? If so, Kindly let me know wt do:)

Comment: You can put a comment on the PR saying you look foward to it for example. Or at least use a github emoji thumb up :)

Answer (score 0):

With new React-Native.
It's complicated fixture of file Package.
So you should remove this **package.json**

> Because new **React-Native** version package will point to new folder path ***fixtures*** instead of **fixtures**. You can Check the path of React-Native package for more detail in folder path as below.

This is what i did:

> rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json

Then restart the packager and run it again.

Comment: So, This package.json file is not required anymore in the further releases of react-native!

Comment: Yeah of cos, Because new **React-Native** package will point to new folder path **__fixtures__** instead of **fixtures**.

Comment: @Seyha--I got confused with your answer. My project folder contains **__fixtures__**  but not **fixtures** and i was suggested to delete package.json which is inside **__fixtures__**. Could you let me know that where can I find the **fixtures** folder?

Comment: Pls refer to the path that I posted in the answer.

Comment: @Seyha--In that path there is **__fixtures__** folder, not **fixture**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My version of RN and Cli is:

> OS: Windows 10

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.53.3
```

I faced the same issue on 0.53 v of React Native, so I went to and renamed:

> node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/package.json
>
> node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/**fixtures**/files/**package**.json.BAK

Just to make sure other things didn't go south so just renamed the package.json file than delete it.

After that I re-ran react-native run-android and it finally worked!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to `android/app/build.gradle` and write this piece of code on the second line after

**apply plugin: "com.android.application"** and write this code

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Then close the application over the emulator or Android Device and start it again right from

```
npm start and react-native run-android
```

If still there is some issues then run `npm link` and start off again with

```
`npm start and react-native run-android`
```

Hope this solves the issue!!